# Spring Boot REST поиск по первым символам

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Делаю Spring-boot back-end rest-приложение.

Ребята на фронте делают поиск, куда пользователь будет вводить наименование, а ему будет выпадать подсказка в виде списка из существующих в БД наименований.

И происходить это должно так сказать онлайн. Т.е. Начал вводить пользователь Н - ему сразу выпал список наименований на Н, продолжил вводить НИ - список подсказок тут же обновляется и т.д.

Как на беке правильно сделать REST?

Сделать в контроллере обработку обычного запроса, например:

```
@GetMapping("/find")
    public Map<String,String> find(
            @ApiParam("name")
            @NotBlank @RequestParam String name) {
        return organizationService.find(name);
    }
```

и соответственно из БД делать выборку запросом вроде:

```
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    Optional<List<Student>> findStudentsByNameStartsWith(String name);
}
```

это то, что пришло мне на ум... Но если в БД будет огромный список и/или БД будет сильно нагружена, то скорость отклика будет низкой...

Может для таких задач существует другое решение?

Comment: Примерно так это и работает. Для повышения производительности колонку, по которой идёт выборка, индексируют.

Answer (score 1):

Вы все правильно делаете, но выбирать все значения в строку поиска очень неоптимально (а если значений будет 100000, а если миллион?).

Учитывая, что это поисковый запрос, то можно решить несколькими способами:

1. Решение в лоб. Добавляете ограничение на количество элементов, пишете вручную запрос и задаете фиксированное количество элементов. Должно получиться что-то такое:

   ```
   public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
       @Query(value = "select * from Students where name = ?1 limit ?2", nativeQuery = true)
       Optional<List<Student>> findStudentsByNameStartsWith(String name, Long limit);
   }
   ```
2. Правильно и с пагинацией

   ```
   public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
       Optional<List<Student>> findStudentsByNameStartsWith(String name, Pageable pageable);
   }
   ```

И полезные ссылки для ознакомления

1. [источник раз](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)
2. [источник два](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)